# mobile change page transisition reverse options not working android 5+ version using cordova application

Tags: android, jquery, windows, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am newbie in cordova. I am trying to develop a mobile application which need to support for all platform.

I am facing a problem while trying to change the two pages in transition reverse mode.

In below android version 4.4.2 and ios platform developed app is working fine. But in above android 5.0 version and windows platform it showing blank page like below image.

[image]

Its happening when the user hitting the back button from mobile. jquery function for transition reversing which is mentioned below.

**`$.mobile.changePage("#mainpage" , { transition: "slide" ,reverse="true"} );`**

If I removed the argument `reverse=true` for above android 5.0 version, the transition reverse mode working fine with below function.

**`$.mobile.changePage("#mainpage" , { transition: "slide" } );`**

I am using jquery1.3.0 version, cordova5.1.1.

Is there is any way to fix the issue for different android version and other platform.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method to do so.. it will work on device's back key down, and if you want to add button on UI for back, then you can call `onBackKeyDown()` on click event of that button

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    console.log('Device ready - register onBackKeyDown()');                
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onBackKeyDown() {

       try{
                        var nav = window.navigator;
                        if( this.phonegapNavigationEnabled && nav && nav.app && nav.app.backHistory )
                        {
                            nav.app.backHistory();
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            window.history.back();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e)
                    {
                     alert(e);
                    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have followed this method only. Instead of calling the nav.app.backHistory(); to  $.mobile.changePage("#mainpage" , { transition: "slide" ,reverse="true"} );. so I used to change the page this way only..

Comment: $.mobile.navigate("#mainpage" , { transition: "slide" ,reverse="true"});

Comment: @vara I will recommend you to go with the answer I provided, as I already tested and implemented it successfully, and also my app is working well on android, iOS and windows (on all versions) with the code I used.

Comment: Thank you... whether its working above android 5+  version,

Comment: But still is same issue happen .. I have tested 5.0.2.. lollipop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91384/discussion-between-sunil-and-vara).

Comment: Sunil Thank you.... I have changed the jquery version 1.3,2 to 1,4,5. Its now working fine.